# Scala empty default closure?

Tags: scala, closures, default-value

just a quick question I seem to be unable to find an answer to.

I have a method definition in Scala that looks like this:

```
def execute(goals: List[String],
            profiles: List[String] = List(),
            loggingCallback: (String) => Unit = { _ => }): Result = {
    // method body
    loggingCallback("a message")
}
```

I would like to know whether there is a better way to specify a default empty closure. The question is not about how to implement logging, this is just an example.

Comment: What is wrong with how you have done it? It's pretty concise!

Comment: I'm not saying there is something wrong about the way i specified it. What I just don't know is whether this specification is sufficient and/or good style.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your solution is fine. You could introduce a type alias for `Function1[X, Unit]`; use `()` as per Kevin's answer, and drop unnecessary parens.

```
scala> type Effect[-A] = (A => Unit)
defined type alias Effect

scala> def foo(f: Effect[String] = _ => ()) = ()
foo: (f: (String) => Unit)Unit
```

You could also define a `noop` function:

```
scala> val noop = (a: Any) => ()
noop: (Any) => Unit = <function1>

scala> def foo(f: Effect[String] = noop) = ()
```

Answer (score 8):

The value `()` is an instance of unit, so this should do the trick:

```
def execute(
  goals: List[String],
  profiles: List[String] = Nil,
  loggingCallback: (String) => Unit = { _ => () }): Result =
{
  // method body
  loggingCallback("a message")
  // do something returning a Result
}
```

**update**

If something is optional, then it often makes more sense to state so explicitly, this also results in better self-documenting code:

```
def execute(
  goals: List[String],
  profiles: List[String] = Nil,
  loggingCallback: Option[(String) => Unit] = None): Result =
{
  // method body
  loggingCallback forEach { _.apply("a message") }
  // do something returning a Result
}
```

**update 2**

DSL-esque situations like this are also one of the very few situations where I'll condone the use of `null` in Scala:

```
def execute(
  goals: List[String],
  profiles: List[String] = Nil,
  loggingCallback: (String) => Unit = null
): Result = {
  // method body
  val log = Option(loggingCallback) getOrElse {_ => ()}
  log("a message")
  // do something returning a Result
}
```

Note the `Option(loggingCallback)` to *immediately* convert the nullable `loggingCallback` into a nice type-safe `Option`, then `getOrElse` to provide a fallback alternative.

Comment: You are right the use of Option here makes things much clearer for callers.